# docker nginx container not starting

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

This is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM nginx

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I use `docker build .` and then `docker run -it 603030818c86` to start my nginx container. But when I go to `http://localhost:8080` it doesn't give me the `nginx` homepage. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You exposing port inside docker network, try to use:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 603030818c86
```

Comment: Gives me `The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.` when going to `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: You run container in foreground mode, try simple `docker run -d -p 8080:80 nginx nginx -g 'daemon off;'`

If it works, then just replace `nginx nginx -g 'daemon off;'` to your image name.